# json_decode yahoo finance data

Tags: php, json, yahoo-finance

I want to get data from yahoo finance json
The url is `https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/USD`

The codes I use are:

```
function get_finance_data(){

    $url ='https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=USD';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = json_decode($result, true);
    return $data;
}
```

and this:

```
public function render()
{
    $financial_entity = array();
    $market_data = $this->get_finance_data();
                $item = array (
                    'symbol'          => $market_data['underlyingSymbol'],
                );
                $financial_entity[] = $item;
            

    var_dump($market_data);
    
}
```

On `var_dump($market_data);` I get the contetnt

```
array(1) { 
  ["quoteResponse"]=> array(2) { 
    ["result"]=> array(1) { 
      [0] => array(59) { 
        ["language"]=> string(5) "en-US" ["region"]=> string(2) "US" ["quoteType"]=> string(3) "ETF" ["quoteSourceName"]=> string(13) "Delayed Quote" ["triggerable"]=> bool(true) ["currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["ytdReturn"]=> float(15.65) ["trailingThreeMonthReturns"]=> float(15.89) ["trailingThreeMonthNavReturns"]=> float(15.65) ["fiftyDayAverage"]=> float(120.12118) ["fiftyDayAverageChange"]=> float(5.0788193) ["fiftyDayAverageChangePercent"]=> float(0.042280797) ["twoHundredDayAverage"]=> float(106.89956) ["twoHundredDayAverageChange"]=> float(18.300438) ["twoHundredDayAverageChangePercent"]=> float(0.17119282) ["sourceInterval"]=> int(15) ["exchangeDataDelayedBy"]=> int(0) ["tradeable"]=> bool(false) ["preMarketChange"]=> float(0) ["preMarketChangePercent"]=> float(0) ["preMarketTime"]=> int(1619428553) ["preMarketPrice"]=> float(125.2) ["regularMarketChange"]=> float(3.9300003) ["regularMarketChangePercent"]=> float(3.240703) ["regularMarketTime"]=> int(1619208000) ["regularMarketPrice"]=> float(125.2) ["regularMarketDayHigh"]=> float(126.1111) ["regularMarketDayRange"]=> string(17) "121.22 - 126.1111" ["regularMarketDayLow"]=> float(121.22) ["regularMarketVolume"]=> int(75592) ["regularMarketPreviousClose"]=> float(121.27) ["bid"]=> float(0) ["ask"]=> float(0) ["bidSize"]=> int(8) ["askSize"]=> int(8) ["fullExchangeName"]=> string(8) "NYSEArca" ["regularMarketOpen"]=> float(121.22) ["averageDailyVolume3Month"]=> int(60909) ["averageDailyVolume10Day"]=> int(51000) ["fiftyTwoWeekLowChange"]=> float(82.729996) ["fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent"]=> float(1.9479631) ["fiftyTwoWeekRange"]=> string(14) "42.47 - 136.25" ["fiftyTwoWeekHighChange"]=> float(-11.050003) ["fiftyTwoWeekHighChangePercent"]=> float(-0.08110094) ["fiftyTwoWeekLow"]=> float(42.47) ["fiftyTwoWeekHigh"]=> float(136.25) ["exchange"]=> string(3) "PCX" ["shortName"]=> string(30) "ProShares Ultra Semiconductors" ["longName"]=> string(30) "ProShares Ultra Semiconductors" ["messageBoardId"]=> string(14) "finmb_32431934" ["exchangeTimezoneName"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" ["exchangeTimezoneShortName"]=> string(3) "EDT" ["gmtOffSetMilliseconds"]=> int(-14400000) ["market"]=> string(9) "us_market" ["esgPopulated"]=> bool(false) ["firstTradeDateMilliseconds"]=> int(1170340200000) ["priceHint"]=> int(2) ["marketState"]=> string(3) "PRE" ["symbol"]=> string(3) "USD" 
      } 
    } 
    ["error"]=> NULL 
  } 
}
```

But what i try to  `var_dump($financial_entity);` I get the NULL for symbol key.

Comment: Well it's very clear to see that `$market_data` doesn't contain a property called `underlyingSymbol`. So what did you expect `$market_data['underlyingSymbol']` to return? Your question makes no sense. You need to select something from `$market_data` which actually exists.

Comment: when i try to print e.x `$market_data['language']` i get just  NULL } }

Comment: That's because market_data doesn't contain that property either. Read the output - it's clearly showing you that "language" is inside an object in an array, which is itself inside another object. It's not at the top level.

Comment: @ADyson this is a full level od language but same NULL `$market_data['optionChain']['result'][0]['language']`

Comment: Don't understand, what it should look like to display the value of `language`?

Comment: `Don't understand` ...don't understand what? `$market_data['optionChain']` makes no sense. Tell me where in that var_dump output you can see the word "optionChain"?? Answer: You can't. It's not there (not even in the inner array). So how do you expect it would return anything if you try to access it from the code? I simply don't see why you would even try that code. Can you explain your logic for using "optionChain"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data item you're requesting - `$market_data['underlyingSymbol']` - doesn't exist in the sample data. You need to access the correct part of the data structure, using the correct property names:

```
'symbol' => $market_data['quoteResponse']['result'][0]['symbol'];
```